# githubにシークレットコードに依存したソースコードを上げるときにベストプラクティス

Tags: github

今日。githubにyoutube APIに依存するコードをプッシュしました。

https://github.com/bamchoh/sofys

ですが、一部コードはローカルにあるので、ビルドする為にはそのコードをgit cloneした人それぞれで書く必要があります。ソースコードを編集されるような場合だとそれも仕方ないかなと思うんですが、使用するだけの人を想定した場合、バイナリ配布を行ったほうがいいのだろうなと思っています。クラウドのCIサービスを使用する場合、シークレットコードをCIサービスに配置する必要があると思いますが、その内容を外部の人に知られないようにする方法はありますか？その場合はプライベートリポジトリを作成してそのリポジトリのバイナリとして作成するほうが良いのでしょうか？（できるかどうかはわからないのですが）

ここでいうシークレットコードは、 OAuth2 のクライアントコードを想定しています。なので、以下の性質があります。

- ソースコードを記述している際には、定まっていない
- バイナリを配布する際には、その中に組み込まれていてほしい

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disclaimer: バイナリの中にシークレットコードを埋め込む以上、頑張ればその情報は復元可能にはなってしまっていると考えます。

CI サービスは、外部からは見えない環境変数 (など) を、そのビルドに対して定義できるようになっているはずだと考えます。また、シェルの実行もできるのではないか、と考えています。

上記を満たすサービスを利用しているのであれば、

1. 置き換えたいシークレットコード部分を適当な、ほかでは利用されない文字列で埋めておく (以下、プレースホルダー)
2. 環境変数でもって、プレースホールダーを置換するシェルを書く
3. 通常のビルドを行う

と私だったら行うと思います。

Comment: 環境変数等でアクセスキーを設定する場合、ユーザーにその情報を提示することになってしまうので、それは避けたいと考えています。

Comment: @YoshihikoYamanaka 環境変数でアクセスキーを設定すると、ユーザーにそれを提示することになってしまう、というのが理解できていないです。。
1. 自分で利用するためにCIサービスでビルドをしたい。
2. CI サービスでビルドするためには、レポジトリに環境変数の内容をコミットしなければならない。
3. しかしレポジトリにコミットするとユーザーに公開されてしまう。

ということでしょうか？

Comment: 提供方法としてバイナリでのユーザー提供を考えており、Oauth2にてyoutubeアカウントとの連携を行いたいと考えています。ユーザーに個々に外部アクセスキーを取得してほしくない（ユーザーに手間をかけさせたくなく、youtubeアカウントを持っていればよい状態にしたい)ので、バイナリに対して、1アクセスキーとしたいと考えています。その場合、ユーザーのローカル環境にバイナリを配置することになるので、環境変数も個々のユーザーに指定してもらう必要があり、その場合、ユーザーにアクセスキーを知ってもらう必要があります。そうすると、私の思惑とは逆にアクセスキーが外部に漏れてしまうということになるので、それは避けたいと思っています。サーバーサイドアプリケーションであれば、サーバーとしてサービス提供者が持っていて、その中で環境変数を指定して動作させることができると思いますが、アプリケーションをユーザー側に提供する場合で、そのアプリケーションが外部アクセスキーを必要とした場合のキーの置き場について何かよい案があれば教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: @YoshihikoYamanaka なるほど、、私の理解を質問に追記したので、認識と齟齬があればロールバックをお願いできますでしょうか。それに併せて、この回答の内容も変えます。